# In Photoshop, is possible to get wet edges effect without opacity buildup?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image: Wet edges build up]

I know the build-up is part of the effect, but is there any way to get the wet edges effect without a build-up? It's okay if the center color is not transparent, just as long as the outer edge color is darker. The darker outer-edge effect is all that I want.

EDIT/UPDATE:

[image]

Both of the bottom 2 effects are 1px 100% opacity. The stroke effect is too jagged. I tried outer glow, which is much smoother, but not varied on edge darkness like wet edges.

Comment: Hi user18670, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: The "I like these wet edges" are strokes. The "But not this buildup" is caused by overlaying two shapes with reduced opacity. They're not at all related.

Comment: I know they're not all related. I tried to explain that I want the edge effect that wet edges provides (darker and smooth, but varied levels of darkness on the edge) without the reduced opacity in the center of the brush stroke that is forced with wet edges. See the updates to my post

Comment: Ooh think I understand. Are you using the "Wet Edges" option in the Brush Panel?

Comment: Yes, that's the one

Answer (score 2):

If it's simply a darker edge that you desire I suggest adding a stroke instead.

Double-click on the desired layer to show the layer style box, select stroke in the sidebar and adjust colour, size, etc. until you achieve the desired result. You can set the position to outside to ensure it wraps your shape.

Comment: I tried that, but it looks very blocky and not smooth and varied like wet edges effect - however, this gave me idea to try outer glow, which is not varied like wet edges, but at least it's smooth -- see the other answer I am about to post for a picture example. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not possible. Outer glow with a dark color and thin border seems to be closest thing possible in Photoshop to the desired effect.